# functions with mutiple variables and lines of calculations

Tags: function-construction

I am almost a new user of Mathematica, my question is that how can I have something like a function or exactly a function that for example gets two inputs (a) and (b), then calculates a+b and a*b. In fact something that gets multiple inputs and does multiple calculations or tasks or in other words function with multiple variables and multiple tasks or lines of calculations.

In my Program I have these initial values : Pr, Mr, Er,r then I want to calculate the lines below :

```
While[Pr > 0, 

 f1 = -(1.47*Mr*
      Er*(1 + Pr/Er)*(1 + 4*\[Pi]*r^3*Pr*.08969/Mr))/(r^2*(1 - 
       2*Mr*1.47/r));
 g1 = 4*\[Pi]*r^2*Er*.08969;
 k1 = h*f1;
 m1 = h*g1;

 f2 = -(1.47*Mr*
      Er*(1 + (Pr + k1/2)/Er)*(1 + 
        4*\[Pi]*(r + h/2)^3*(Pr + k1/2)*.08969/Mr))/((r + h/2)^2*(1 - 
       2*Mr*1.47/(r + h/2)));
 g2 = 4*\[Pi]*(r + h/2)^2*(Er + m1/2)*.08969;
 k2 = h*f2;
 m2 = h*g2;
 f3 = -(1.47*Mr*
      Er*(1 + (Pr + k2/2)/Er)*(1 + 
        4*\[Pi]*(r + h/2)^3*(Pr + k2/2)*.08969/Mr))/((r + h/2)^2*(1 - 
       2*Mr*1.47/(r + h/2)));
 g3 = 4*\[Pi]*(r + h/2)^2*(Er + m2/2)*.08969;
 k3 = h*f3;
 m3 = h*g3;

 f4 = -(1.47*Mr*
      Er*(1 + (Pr + k3)/Er)*(1 + 
        4*\[Pi]*(r + h)^3*(Pr + k3)*.08969/Mr))/((r + h)^2*(1 - 
       2*Mr*1.47/(r + h)));
 g4 = 4*\[Pi]*(r + h)^2*(Er + m3)*.08969;
 k4 = h*f4;
 m4 = h*g4;

 Pr = Pr + 1/6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
 Mr = Mr + 1/6*(m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4);
 Er = fromPressureToEnergy[Pr];
 r = r + h;
 ]
```

```
 The results are the last Mr and r when the loop is finished.
```

Could you please help me that how i can write a function for this code and calculations?

Comment: E.g. `f[a_, b_] := { a + b, a b} `.

Comment: see also [Through](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) in the documentation center. E.g. `ClearAll[f]; f[a_, b_] := Through[{Plus, Times, h, foo}[a, b]]; f[a, b]`

Comment: There are also `Module`, `Block`, `With`.

Comment: In fact a function that has multiple inputs which has different lines that each of them dose some calculations with the inputs.

Comment: I said `Module`. Read documentation pages.

Comment: Pleas read through an introductory tutorial ([like this one](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/)) in full. The one I linked is less than 30 pages, covers all essentials, and comes with exercises.

Comment: It looks like Runge-Kutta 4 method. Notice that mathematica has all possible numerical methods for the solution of differential equations. Check `NDSolve`. Also try to avoid having all these numbers like `.08969` around-- easy to mistype. Introduce a constant. Use functions for the parts of code that are used repeatedly. These simple rules apply to any other programming language, not only mathematica. Try to be efficient in programming.

Comment: yes, it is exactly a Runge-Kutta 4,

Comment: What i need is to use the hole code as a function, based on the explanations above I can use Module for this purpose. If you have any idea please let me know

Comment: does the syntax `f[Pr0_, Mr0_, Er0_, r0_] := Module[{Pr=Pr0,Mr=Mr0,Er=Er0,r=r0,<any-other-variables-you-want-to-be-local> },<your-code-as-is>; {Mr,r}]`, as implicitly suggested, not work for what you're trying to do? or was it simply difficult to parse that that was what was being suggested, given your newness to Mathematica? Welcome, by the way! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks every one for your help and attention.